# How to embed output of one tex into another tex as figures?

Tags: beamer, embedding, scrbook

I'd like to embed the slides of one of my tex files with `documentclass` `beamer` as thumbnails into another tex file with `documentclass` `scrbook`. For example: the slides of the beamer file shall be arranged in two columns on one or two pages of the second tex file.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Something like [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) can be ok?

Comment: Need to investigate it. Looks promising.

Comment: Alright, almost... One last thing I'm missing is how to put the pages into the page layout of the parent document. The pages where the slides are placed on don't have page numbers, header and footer. The layout of the parent document does. And the pages with the embedded slides are also being counted which reflects in the last page before the slides being number 36 and the first one after being number 39. **TL;DR** I need the parent document's layout to be applied to the pages with the embedded slides as well.

Comment: Add option `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{yourpagestyle}}` to `includepdf` command.

Comment: Okay, and which pagestyle is the default pagestyle of the parent page?

Comment: I don't use `scrbook` but may be something like `scrplain`, `scrheadings`.

Comment: Alright, I figured that pagestyle headings does what I need.

Comment: If you already solved your problem, would you mind to write an answer? It will be useful for future references.

Comment: Ah, sorry. No, I don't mind... just give me some time.

Comment: @HendrikWiese As already requested, could you write up what you did as an answer?

Comment: Ah, damn, I forgot about this one here... sorry! Give me just another second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did this now, using `includepdf`:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includepdf[scale=0.50,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}},offset=4mm -25mm,delta=1mm 1mm,nup=1x2,pages={1-2}]{af}
\end{figure}
```

This results in the selected PDF pages to be embedded in the parent PDF in the exact way I wanted. Two pages vertically centered one above the other (I decided that one column suits my needs much better).

Comment: af is the name of the PDF. Just to mention...